# Execute Jar file with arguments using Gradle task in Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jar, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to run an external Jar file with arguments that I have saved in my project. The function doesn't seem to work. I am not sure if the syntax is correct.

```kotlin
tasks.register("myGradleTask", Exec::class) {
  val folder = "${rootProject.rootDir}/myFolder/"
  val jarFilePath = "${rootProject.rootDir}/Scripts/MyExternalJarFile.jar"
  executable(jarFilePath)
  commandLine(arrayOf("java", "-jar", "-app AppName -i $folder -o $folder"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html) class which is specifically designed for executing JVM programs (assuming you have the java plugin applied).

One mistake you look to be making is passing the Kotlin `KClass` to the `register` method rather than the Java `Class`.

Try this:

```
tasks.register("myGradleJavaExec", JavaExec::class.java) {
    val folder = "${rootProject.rootDir}/myFolder/"
    val jarFilePath = "${rootProject.rootDir}/Scripts/MyExternalJarFile.jar"
    classpath = files(jarFilePath)
    args("-app", "AppName", "-i", folder, "-o", folder) // Specify args separately
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I got thrown off by the error of mismatch type in args where Object is required but String were being provided. I guess this is a bug in Android Studio/Gradle/DSL.